# Different md5sums for same tar contents

Tags: tar, md5

I run a test creating two tars from the same dir (its files remained unchanged), and I found that their md5sums were different. I assume there's some timestamp being included in the tar's header, but I haven't found the way to override it. My OS is Ubuntu 9.1. Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: Show the tar commandline that you are using. There shouldn't be any difference unless the files are being modified. Even `touch filename` which changes the modified time of a file is enough to change the checksum.

Comment: Here's the command:

tar czf one.tgz ./bin;
tar czf two.tgz ./bin

.Then both md5s are different.

Comment: It's not tar itself, it seems to be gzip. If you use j for bzip2 instead, it gives the same md5sum. It might be a bug - I tried it on Cygwin and got the same checksum. (I have Ubuntu 9.10, too, and have been getting different results there, just like you.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Dennis pointed out above, it's gzip.  Part of the gzip header is a mod time for whatever is compressed in the file.  If you need gzip, you can compress the tarfile as an extra step outside of tar rather than using tar's internal gzip.  The gzip command has a flag to suppress the saving of that modification time.

```
tar -c ./bin |gzip -n >one.tgz
tar -c ./bin |gzip -n >two.tgz
md5sum one.tgz two.tgz
```

This will not affect times inside the tarfile, only the one in the gzip header.

Comment: It is also possible to pass gzip options to tar like `GZIP=-n tar -cz ...`

Answer (score 8):

To make a tar file with a consistent checksum, just prepend `GZIP=-n` like this:

```
GZIP=-n tar -zcf myOutputTarball.tar /home/luke/directoryIWantToZip
```

**How this works:** Tar can accept gzip options using a temporary `GZIP` environment variable, as above. Like Valter said, tar uses gzip, which by default puts a timestamp in the archive. This means you get a different checksum when you compress the same files. The `-n` option disables that timestamp.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem too, to make gzip do not alter the timestamp, use `gzip -n`

-n, --no-name     do not save or restore the original name and time stamp

```
[valter.silva@alog ~]$ gzip --help
Usage: gzip [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Compress or uncompress FILEs (by default, compress FILES in-place).

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.

  -c, --stdout      write on standard output, keep original files unchanged
  -d, --decompress  decompress
  -f, --force       force overwrite of output file and compress links
  -h, --help        give this help
  -l, --list        list compressed file contents
  -L, --license     display software license
  -n, --no-name     do not save or restore the original name and time stamp
  -N, --name        save or restore the original name and time stamp
  -q, --quiet       suppress all warnings
  -r, --recursive   operate recursively on directories
  -S, --suffix=SUF  use suffix SUF on compressed files
  -t, --test        test compressed file integrity
  -v, --verbose     verbose mode
  -V, --version     display version number
  -1, --fast        compress faster
  -9, --best        compress better
    --rsyncable   Make rsync-friendly archive

With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

Report bugs to <bug-gzip@gnu.org>.
```

Example:

```
[valter.silva@alog ~]$ ls
renewClaroMMSCanaisSemanal.log.gz  s3

[valter.silva@alog ~]$ gunzip renew.log.gz 
[valter.silva@alog ~]$ gunzip s3/renew.log.gz 

[valter.silva@alog ~]$ md5sum renew.log 
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  renew.log

[valter.silva@alog ~]$ md5sum s3/renew.log 
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  s3/renew.log

[valter.silva@alog ~]$ gzip -n renew.log 
[valter.silva@alog ~]$ gzip -n s3/renew.log 

[valter.silva@alog ~]$ md5sum renew.log.gz 
7029066c27ac6f5ef18d660d5741979a  renew.log.gz

[valter.silva@alog ~]$ md5sum s3/renew.log.gz 
7029066c27ac6f5ef18d660d5741979a  s3/renew.log.gz
```

Answer (score 3):

I went down a rabbit-hole after the other answers failed me, and managed to figure out that my version of tar (1.27.1 from  the openSUSE 42.3 OSS repo) was using the non-deterministic `pax` archival format by default, which means that even without compression, (and even setting the mtime explicitly) archives created with tar from the same files would differ:

```
$ echo hi > test.file
$ tar --create --to-stdout test.file # long form of `tar cO test.file`
./PaxHeaders.13067/test.file0000644000000000000000000000013213427447703012603 xustar0030 mtime=1549684675.835011178
30 atime=1549684726.410510251
30 ctime=1549684675.835011178
test.file0000644000175000001440000000000313427447703013057 0ustar00hartusers00000000000000hi
$ tar --create --to-stdout test.file
./PaxHeaders.13096/test.file0000644000000000000000000000013213427447703012605 xustar0030 mtime=1549684675.835011178
30 atime=1549684726.410510251
30 ctime=1549684675.835011178
test.file0000644000175000001440000000000313427447703013057 0ustar00hartusers00000000000000hi
```

**Note that the output above differs, even though no compression is being used**; the uncompressed archive contents (generated by running tar twice on the same contents) are different, so the compressed content will also differ even when using `GZIP=-n` as other answers suggest

## **In order to get around this, you can specify** `--format gnu` :

```
$ tar --create --format gnu --to-stdout test.file
test.file0000644000175000001440000000000313427447703011557 0ustar  hartusershi
$ tar --create --format gnu --to-stdout test.file
test.file0000644000175000001440000000000313427447703011557 0ustar  hartusershi
```

This works with the suggestion about gzip above:

```
# gzip refuses to write to stdout, so we'll use the `-f` option to create a file
$ GZIP=-n tar --format gnu -czf test.file.tgz test.file && md5sum test.file.tgz
0d8c7b3bdbe8066b516e3d3af60ade75  test.file.tgz
$ GZIP=-n tar --format gnu -czf test.file.tgz test.file && md5sum test.file.tgz
0d8c7b3bdbe8066b516e3d3af60ade75  test.file.tgz

# without GZIP=-n we see a different hash
$ tar --format gnu -czf test.file.tgz test.file && md5sum test.file.tgz
682ce0c8267b90f4103b4c29903c5a8d  test.file.tgz
```

However, in addition to [valid reasons to prefer better compression formats to gzip](http://imoverclocked.blogspot.com/2015/12/for-love-of-bits-stop-using-gzip.html), **you might want to consider using xz instead** (which tar also supports with the `--xz` or `-J` flags instead of `-z`), because it saves you a step here; the default behaviour of `xz` is to generate the same compressed output when the uncompressed contents are the same, so there's no need to specify an option like `GZIP=-n` :

```
$ tar --format gnu --xz -cf test.file.txz test.file && md5sum test.file.txz 
dea99037d4b0ee4565b3639e93ac0930  test.file.txz
$ tar --format gnu --xz -cf test.file.txz test.file && md5sum test.file.txz 
dea99037d4b0ee4565b3639e93ac0930  test.file.txz
```